# How to pass the x: Name of a control to another class and set values to the properties

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an `Entry` which has an `x:Name` and I want to set text to it in another class, I would like to use `Text` property in another class. Is it possible to do this? I have tried this code but it does not work, the method `Check()` is called but the text is not applied.

Control class:

```
  public Entry MyEntry
        {
            //entrycontrol is the x:Name of the Entry
            get { return entrycontrol; }
        }
  public Control(){
            InitializeComponent();
            var vr = new MyMethods();
            vr.Check();
  }
```

MyMethods class:

```
 public async Task Check()
        {
           var page = new Control();

           page.MyEntry.Text = "Hello World";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case , you create a new page in the method **Check** , not the original Control.

You need to pass the current Control to the class .

```
public class MyMethods
    {
        Control CurrentControl;

        public MyMethods(Control currentControl)
        {
            CurrentControl = currentControl;
        }

        public async Task Check()
        {
         
           Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> {


                Control.MyEntry.Text = "Hello World";

            });
        }
    }
```

```
var vr = new MyMethods(this);
vr.Check();
```